# Mem read and write at same index and in same cycle

Tags: scala, chisel

For example :
() means Mem address index

at cycle 10

Mem(5) data = 5

at cycle 11

read Mem(5)

write 3 to Mem(5)

What is the behavior at cycle 11?

(1)It gets the data 5 first and then writes 3 to Mem(5). At cycle 12 Mem(5) data =3.

(2)Or it writes data 3 to Mem(5) first, and then read out data? The read out data also is 5.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chisel3 wiki page [wiki/Memories](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Memories)

> If the same Mem address is both written and sequentially read on the
>   same clock edge, or if a sequential read enable is cleared, then the
>   read data is undefined.